# How to get inner list count?

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List`, 'bigList' which holds a `List` of my custom classes. So if I have 20 lists inside my 'bigList', how do I get the count of one of the inner lists?

```
List<List<myClass>> bigList = new List<List<myClass>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
     List<myClass> newList = new List<myClass>();

     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     {
          newList.Add(myClass);
     }
     bigList.Add(newList);
}
```

With this example how do I get the count of the lists inside the bigList? I have not worked with `List` as much as `ArrayList` am I doing this wrong because I would have just stored the lists in an `ArrayList` then used the index to figure out the count of the lists.

Comment: why can't you do bigList.Count?

Comment: bigList.Count is the count of all of my list, which is 20 correct, which is not what I am asking for. I need the count of the inner lists.

Comment: A `List` is just an `ArrayList` that doesn't require casting, has some additional methods, and doesn't box values.  However you would have solve it using an `ArrayList`, you can do with your list, and it'll just require less casting.

Comment: Just to clarify the above for anyone who reads this - `List` is **not** an `ArrayList` - it does not inherit from it or use one internally - it is simply like it except it is generic .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the `i`th list's `Count` property, do the following:

```
var s = bigList[i].Count;
```

To get the total items inside each of the inner lists, do this:

```
bigList.Sum(x => x.Count);
```

Comment: No problem, just remember to upvote the answers that help you and accept the one which answered your question the best when you can :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// To get the number of Lists which bigList holds
bigList.Count();

// To get the number of items in each List of bigList
bigList.Select(x => new {List = x, Count = x.Count()});

// To get the count of all items in all Lists of bigList
bigList.Sum(x => x.Count());
```

Comment: You probably don't want to use the `Count()` LINQ extension method in this case as it enumerates through the list taking `O(n)` time - use the List's `Count` property instead to get the length of the list in constant time.

Comment: @CallumRogers Actually, LINQ's `Count()` method has an optimization; if the provided sequence can be cast to an `ICollection` it does so and uses it's `Count` property, so in this case it is actually O(1).

Comment: @Servy: Just decompiled it and it's seems you are right: http://pastebin.com/hj8r0YjT! However, this optimisation is implementation dependent - I don't know for example if mono or Portable.NET would do this, where as the `Count` property is `O(1)` on all of them.

Comment: @CallumRogers Well, technically, there fact that `Count` is O(1) is also implementation dependent.  At this point the behavior is so well know and relied upon that there is no way they would make the breaking change to remove the optimization, especially considering how easy it is to implement.

Comment: Also, I wondered why the microsoft code didn't use `static int Count<TSource>(this ICollection<TSource> source)` instead - but this is because extension methods are static and so don't have any kind of virtual dispatch; you're forced to do the hacky workaround that is visible in their code.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
bigList.Sum(smallList => smallList.Count ());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (List<myClass> innerList in bigList)
{
     int count = innerList.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
foreach(var innerList in bigList)
    var size = innerList.Count; //use the size variable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bigList[0].Count; //accesses the first element of the big list and retrieves the number of elements of that list item
```

Or, in a foreach loop for every element in the big list:

```
for (var item in bigList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Count); // print number of elements for every sublist in bigList
}
```

List/ArrayList all implement the IList interface so you can use them in the same way.